# Guess XML's root element attributes from schema

Tags: php, xml, xsd

I'm not very keen on XML but I must generate and validate some XML files from according to a XSD file.

I created the xml file but it fails to validate because I don't know how to get namespace nor anything like that.

My XML file is something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<REMITTable1>
  <reportingEntityID>CB8899899, ACE</reportingEntityID>
  <contractList>
    <contract>
      <contractId>78</contractId>
      <contractName>Nombre asignado al contrato1</contractName>
      <contractType>CO</contractType>
      <energyCommodity>NG</energyCommodity>
      <fixingIndex>
        <indexName/>
        <indexValue>2.3</indexValue>
...
...
```

And my xsd Schema starts with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- edited with XMLSpy v2014 rel. 2 sp1 (x64) (http://www.altova.com) by - - (Agency for the Cooperation of Energy Regulators) -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ait1="http://www.acer.europa.eu/REMIT/REMITTable1_V2.xsd" targetNamespace="http://www.acer.europa.eu/REMIT/REMITTable1_V2.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="REMITTable1">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="reportingEntityID" type="ait1:reportingEntityID">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Field No. 6, 7</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="contractList" type="ait1:contractListType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="OrderList" type="ait1:OrderListType" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:unique name="OrderRecordSeqNumber">
                        <xs:selector xpath="ait1:OrderReport"/>
                        <xs:field xpath="ait1:RecordSeqNumber"/>
                    </xs:unique>
                </xs:element>
```

I know, there are some attributes I should add ot the REMITTable1 element but, I don't know which they are. I've been googling around but I cannot get a clue of how to do it.

Does anybody know how should I do it?. Thanks.

Comment: How do you create the XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You XSD defines a target namespace, so you need to create an XML that contains nodes with that namespace.

In DOM you will have to use `DOMDocument::createElementNS()`:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->appendChild(
  $document->createElementNS(
    'http://www.acer.europa.eu/REMIT/REMITTable1_V2.xsd', 
    'REMITTable1'
  )
);

echo $document->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<REMITTable1 xmlns="http://www.acer.europa.eu/REMIT/REMITTable1_V2.xsd"/>
```

You can use an alias/prefix for the namespace, too.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->appendChild(
  $document->createElementNS(
    'http://www.acer.europa.eu/REMIT/REMITTable1_V2.xsd', 
    'ait1:REMITTable1'
  )
);

echo $document->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ait1:REMITTable1 xmlns:ait1="http://www.acer.europa.eu/REMIT/REMITTable1_V2.xsd"/>
```

Namespace nodes use the same syntax as attribute nodes, but they are added automatically if you use the namespace aware methods.

SimpleXML is a little different. You always have to create the document element by loading an XML.

```
$element = new SimpleXmlElement(
  '<REMITTable1 xmlns="http://www.acer.europa.eu/REMIT/REMITTable1_V2.xsd"/>'
);
$element->addChild('contractList', null, 'http://www.acer.europa.eu/REMIT/REMITTable1_V2.xsd');

echo $element->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<REMITTable1 xmlns="http://www.acer.europa.eu/REMIT/REMITTable1_V2.xsd"><contractList/></REMITTable1>
```

If you do not provide the namespace argument to SimpleXmlElement it will use the namespace of the parent node.

Comment: Finally, I started using @cvesters solution with DOMDocument. Fortunatelly, a simple find and replace work to add prefix "rem:" to all the elements.

Thank you both of you.

Answer (score 2):

By adding

```
xmlns="http://www.acer.europa.eu/REMIT/REMITTable1_V2.xsd"
```

You specify that as your default namespace. You can also use a prefix for the namespace by adding

```
xmlns:remit="http://www.acer.europa.eu/REMIT/REMITTable1_V2.xsd"
```

But then you would have to change your entire xml as every element than needs to be prefixed with

```
remit:
```

Though I don't like to use the default namespace myself, as I think it's more confusing then having an explicit namespace. But in this case it may be too much work to change the entire XML document, and add the prefix to every element.